# Passing C++ string to a c# function

Tags: c#, c++, string, interop

I'm wrapping Microsoft's assert class in c# and want to use that code in c++. The issue I'm having has to deal with the info strings and I'm not quite sure how to pass a c++ string to a c# method. Both are managed.

```
//c# Assert wrapper
static public bool AreEqual<T>(T expected, T actual, string info){
    //...
    WriteLine(info);
    //...
}
```

called from c++

```
//c++
void someCppFunc(){
    long expected = 2;
    long actual = 2;
    Assert::AreEqual<long>(expected, actual, L"Some info message");
}
```

But the error I get says it has no matching function. How would I go about this?

Comment: IMO, you're better off using a native C++ unit-test library like Boost.Test, google test or [Catch](https://github.com/philsquared/Catch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass it a managed string instead of a native C++ one:

```
//c++/clr
void someCppFunc(){
    long expected = 2;
    long actual = 2;
    Assert::AreEqual<long>(expected, actual, gcnew System::String(L"Some info message"));
}
```